# Find hidden (or not hidden) double quotes in file using linux

Tags: csv, grep, double-quotes

I need to convert a file from comma separated to pipe delimited.  I plan on using sed `'s/,/|/g'` - I have tested on dummy data and this has worked for me.

However, before I execute the "sed" command, how can I find out if my data file contains double quotes?  It has been requested to have the file converted to pipe delimited without any double quotes.  This is a fairly large file (4+ million rows) and wondering if there is a way (perhaps 'grep' command) in linux that would quickly identify any double quotes in the file.  Since this is a csv file, there is a chance a business entity may contain double quotes (i.e. "business name, inc").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Checking whether there are any double quotes is quite straightforward, for example by inspecting the exit code of `grep -q '"' infile`. Converting such a file correctly requires properly parsing the CSV file, though - which one are you asking about?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Benjamin.  Full transparency - I am very new to using things like "sed" and continue to expand my knowledge using linux.  In short, I am trying to do two key things with this file 1) convert it from csv to pipe delimited and 2) remove any double quotes.  As noted in the original message, this is a large .csv file.  I am open to any suggestions/commands I could use to get the results I need. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually used `grep ' " ' <filename.csv>` and that seemed to work.  I tested searching for specific names in the file and got my results `grep ' <term> ' <filename.csv` and got results.  Got zero results when searching for the double quotes so it looks like we don't have any in the file.  Thanks for the help, Benjamin!